# Plot pie chart of data in a particular column

Tags: python, pandas, pie-chart

Suppose I have a csv data like this with thousand of rows

```
| Src_Mac_address    |Dst_Mac_address2|    Src_Mac_country|
1    x1               y1                    Country1          
2    x2               y2                    Country2
3    x3               y3                    Country3
4    x4               y4                    Country4
5    x5               y5                    Country5
6    x6               y6                    Country1
7    x7               y7                    Country1
8    x8               y8                    Country2
```

I want to find out the frequency of each country in `Src_mac_country` column and want to plot the pie chart with percentage share of that country. There are more than 30 countries in `Src_mac_country` column, but I only want to plot top-10 countries according to their No. of occurences (descending order).

I tried

```
df=pd.read_csv('Filepath')
#df['Src_Mac_country'].value_counts()
#df.Src_Mac_country.value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).round(1).astype(str)+'%'
```

This shows how many times each country has occured in `Src_Mac_country`.
Next line shows the percentage of that country of that column(i.e `Src_Mac_country`).

But I want to plot this data in pie chart and I want to plot top 10 countries only,according to their percentage of occurence(descending order).

How can I do that?

Comment: Yes ,it is working but I cannot see the percentage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `head` for filter top N rows, for percentages add `autopct='%1.1f%%'`:

```
N = 10
df.Src_Mac_country.value_counts(normalize=True).head(N).plot.pie(autopct='%1.1f%%')
```

Or id need also plot all other categories sum together:

```
N = 10
s = df.Src_Mac_country.value_counts(normalize=True).head(N)
s.loc['other'] = 1 - s.sum()
s.plot.pie(autopct='%1.1f%%')
```